# How to automatically set "Always on visible workspace" for windows on particular monitor

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, workspaces

In my dual monitor set up, I generally use my (larger) left hand monitor for working on. I'll have a browser workspace, a text editor workspace, and email workspace and so on. However, the smaller right hand monitor is reserved for "sticky" things like my IRC window, and my music player.

Currently I achieve this by manually setting "Always on visible workspace" for all the windows I place on the right hand workspace, but I'd like to know if there is a way to set it automatically for ones I place there, or if that is the kind of thing that is in the realm of a more wacky window manager. I suspect the answer is going to be "Use XMonad", but I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: I have no experience with what you're trying to do, but, if you don't get a better solution, you might look into using AutoKey macros to automate the processes you use to open windows on your second desktop and set their window/display properties at the same time. https://code.google.com/p/autokey/

Comment: Still looking for an answer? What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I am, and running 14.04.

Comment: Look up a package named devilspie2. It can be used to do this, but it's not a perfect answer since it can be tricky to configure and isn't 100% bug free.