# Switching workspaces on primary display only

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I'd like to be able to switch workspaces only on the primary monitor and make the secondary monitor static.

If I remember correctly this can easily be done in Gnome but I can't find this option in Unity.

I'm aware of similar questions already asked but none of them have an answer.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone encountering this issue, or the inverse, in 18.04+, you can change this behavior using the Gnome Tweak Tool:

### Install

```bash
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

### Run

```bash
gnome-tweaks
```

...or hit <kbd>super</kbd> and search "Tweaks"

### Config

- select "Workspaces" from the left-hand list (at the bottom)
- under "Display Handling", select

  - "Workspaces on primary display only" (for all other displays as
    "static")
  - "Workspaces span displays" (for all displays as a single, shared workspace)

Ref: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1767564/comments/6

Answer (score 1):

The gnome-tweak-took on Gnome version 42.2 doesn't support workspaces anymore! but you can use its alternatives like `dconf-editor`.

Workspaces tab supported two main functionalities, making workspaces static or dynamic, and use it on the primary display only.
All these customization have been added to gnome's built-in setting in `Settings > Multitasking`. There are also other ways, for the first one follow [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490847/set-static-number-of-workspaces-in-gnome-shell-with-dconf) and for the second one follow [this one](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/workspaces-seem-to-only-apply-to-the-primary-display-is-this-a-feature-or-a-bug).

Comment: `$ gsettings set org.gnome.mutter workspaces-only-on-primary false`

Comment: I have Gnome 42.5 and even though "Workspace on primary display only" is configured, every time I switch workspace, applications on my secondary display switch also. They should stay fixed independently of my workspace.

Answer (score 0):

To make a secondary monitor *seem* static, I simply set "Always on Visible Workspace" for the windows on it. (See eg. [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/449089/615551) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/339250/615551)).